# Frequency modulation of $m(t)$ in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, modulation, frequency-modulation

I have a message signal defined in the below interval
$$
m(t)=\begin{cases}1&, 0\leq t < \frac{t_0}{3}\\[2ex]
-2&, \frac{t_0}{3}\leq t <\frac{2t_0}{3}\\[2ex]
0&, \frac{2t_0}{3}\leq t < t_0\end{cases}
$$

where $t_0 = 0.15\ \rm seconds$, and sampling frequency $F_s=2\ \rm kHz$.

My MATLAB code in order to construct $m(t)$

```
t0= 0.15;
Fs= 2000;
t1= 0:1/Fs:t0/3- 1/Fs;
t2= t0/3:1/Fs:2*t0/3 - 1/Fs;
t3= 2*t0/3:1/Fs:3*t0/3-1/Fs;
m1= ones([1, length(t1)]);
m2= -2*ones([1, length(t2)]);
m3= zeros([1, length(t3)]);
m= [m1, m2, m3];
t= [t1, t2, t3];
```

I'm trying to find frequency modulation and the following formula is wanted to be used
$$
x_{FM}(t) = \cos\left(2 \pi  f_c t + 2\pi  k_f \int_{-\infty}^t m(x) dx\right)
$$
with carrier frequency $f_c=200$Hz and deviation constant $k_f= 50$.

Only for or while loops are allowed while we find integral. In order to integrate, I have made this for loop

```
result=0;
j=1;

for i= 0:1/Fs:t0- 1/Fs
   result= result + m(j);

    %% result2 will be used as we integrate it over 0 to 0.15
   result2(j) = result;
   j= j+1;
end
```

Please tell me, is something wrong with this integration?
I plotted this and it seems correct to me.

[image]

If the integration is true, then why frequency didn't change at all when plotting this signal.

```
xFM= cos(2*pi*fc*t + 2*pi*kf*result)
```

[image]

Full code [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fcbpKxrRZq/)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `result2` when calculating `xFM`? `result` is a constant.

Comment: I don't know. I tried but it didn't change. Couldn't it be constant because when we take integral of message signal from 0 to 0.15s, it would be constant

Comment: `result` is a constant by the time you use it. `result2` contains the integral from 0 to `j/Fs` in index `j`. What is the maximum value of `kf*result2`? Maybe your frequency deviation is very small and that's the reason you don't see it in your plot.

Comment: Problem solved when I took dx interval 1/Fs because I used to integrate it with dx= 1 before. And I also had to change result to result2..Thanks

Comment: @UygarUçar do you think you can post this as an answer and accept it too, so that we can close this question gracefully? Otherwise, it will keep circulating in the board as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration was incorrect. I was integrating it with $dx= 1$. Doing `m(j)*1/Fs`operation in the for loop, I have made $dx= 1/Fs$ now.

As can be seen, frequency changes for different amplitudes now.
[image]

Moreover, `result`is a constant, it should be changed to`result2` so that it gives result with respect to time $t$.

Comment: In a day or so, when the system lets you, please mark this as the accepted answer.